# macOS Mojave update - what was updated?

Tags: macos, software-update, mojave

My macOS laptop showed a prompt top-right of the screen to restart and install updates. It took about 30 minutes so I guess it was something serious.

Now MySQL (through brew) won't start so I'm looking for clues.

**Is there a way to see release notes for recently installed macOS updates?**

I found a list in System Information > Software > Installations, ordered by install date, and it shows two entries for "macOS 10.14.2 Update" with today's date but it doesn't give any more information.

Knowing what was updated might point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Try starting the mysql daemon manually - what errors do you get?

Comment: Thanks @Allan but maybe I shouldn't have mentioned the MySQL problem as it's a whole other topic ;) I finally found the daemon logs so I'm closer to solving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Apple's Downloads

Apple provide release notes for each update in the [macOS Downloads](https://support.apple.com/en_US/downloads/macos) section of their support site.

As an example, [macOS Mojave 10.14.2 Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1986), states:

> The macOS Mojave 10.14.2 update improves the stability, compatibility and security of your Mac, and is recommended for all users.
>
> This update:
>
> - Adds RTT (real-time text) support for Wi-Fi calling
> - Adds a menu item to News for opening a story in Safari
> - Resolves an issue that may prevent iTunes from playing media to third- party AirPlay speakers.
>
> For more detailed information about this update, please visit: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT209149
>
> For detailed information about the security content of this update, please visit: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201222

Follow the **detailed information** links for specific changes that are included.